# .NET Minification and adding new bundles at runtime

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, bundling-and-minification

I've read through some other posts and tried some different methods but none of them worked. I want to rebuild the .NET Minification BundleTable without restarting the website so that I can add new folders with new CSS files at a new bundle name.

I tried the following from a controller method:

```
BundleTable.Bundles.Clear();
BundleTable.Bundles.ResetAll();
//this is where the magic happens
//var context = new BundleContext(new HttpContextWrapper(System.Web.HttpContext.Current), BundleTable.Bundles, );
BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
```

the `BundleConfig.RegisterBundles` has all the "`bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/css/_layoutCSS").Include("~/css/_layout.css"));`" etc for whatever I need inside.

But if I add new bundles, trying to reference them by name in the website gives a 404 Not Found javascript console error that the bundle was not found. If I restart the website it works again.

How do I force .NET to refresh the minification bundles list? Someone said that maybe you need to replace the Context somehow but I wasn't able to do it (its part of the comment that is unused).

Comment: You should just be able to create a bundle that includes `*` for a folder, and then drop your new scripts in that folder (instead of creating a new bundle) so they can be picked up. That would work, just don't know if that is what you are looking for. If you modify a `.cs` you'll have to recompile the site.

Comment: I have the same issue. Have you got your solution yet?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try just adding to the BundleTable without clearing or resetting and without calling RegisterBundles? Like this:

```
public ActionResult About()
    {
        BundleTable.Bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/testcss/StyleSheet1").Include(
                  "~/testcss/StyleSheet1.css"));

        return View();
    }
```

Comment: Yes pretty sure I did this. From everything that I found, either the bundle context has to be replaced/destroyed or its just not possible at all so wondering if anyone has a solution

Comment: I'll try it again when I have time but my complete case is where I create the subdirectory and files right before the Bundles.Add, and the subdirectory would be in ~/Views/Parent/NewFolder where Views and Parent already exist. Also I was trying to clear the entire bundle table and regenerate it, not just add one new item. Basically a typical UI to create these files with a Save button. I could add some code to check if it's already in the bundles list so that I can rely on Bundle.Add like your example